# javascript loop odd/even in array

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, loops

I'm trying to do a loop in a array that sorts the content and create div's with 2 values each.

Tried a lot of things, but I can't figure it out what I need to do.

This is what I need to do: loop in a array and create div's. Each div should have 2 values for the array. Like this:

```
<div id="1">content, content 2</div>
<div id="2">content 3, content 4</div>
<div id="3">content 5, content 6</div>
<div id="4">content 7</div>
```

So I have the array like this:

```
var myArray = ['content', 'content 2', 'content 3', 'content 4', 'content 5', 'content 6', 'content 7'];
```

And I'm looping like this:

```
for(var i=0; i<=myArray.length; i++){

    if(currentDiv == 1){
        $('#s'+currendDivID+'').append("<p>"+myArray[i]+"</p>");
            console.log(myArray[i]);
    }

    if(currentDiv == 2){
            $('#s'+currendDivID+'').append("<p>"+myArray[i]+"</p>");
            console.log(myArray[i]);
            $('#container').append("</div>");
    }



    console.log(currendDivID);

    if(currentDiv == 3){
        currendDivID ++;
        $('#container').append("<div id=\"s" + currendDivID + "\">");
        console.log(myArray[i]);
        $('#s'+currendDivID+'').append("<p>"+myArray[i]+"</p>");
    }

    if(currentDiv == 4){
        console.log(myArray[i]);
        $('#s'+currendDivID+'').append("<p>"+myArray[i]+"</p>");
        $('#container').append("</div>");
    }



    console.log(currendDivID);

    if(currentDiv == 5){
        currendDivID++;
        $('#container').append("<div id=\"s" + currendDivID + "\">");
        console.log(myArray[i]);
        $('#s'+currendDivID+'').append("<p>"+myArray[i]+"</p>");
    }

    if(currentDiv == 6){
        if(myArray[i] == undefined){
            return;
        }
        console.log(myArray[i]);
        $('#s'+currendDivID+'').append("<p>"+myArray[i]+"</p>");
        $('#container').append("</div>");
    }


    if(currentDiv == 7){
        currendDivID++;
            if(myArray[i] == undefined){
                $('#container').append("</div>");
                return;
            }
        $('#container').append("<div id=\"s" + currendDivID + "\">");
        console.log(myArray[i]);
        $('#s'+currendDivID+'').append("<p>"+myArray[i]+"</p>");
    }

    currentDiv ++;

}
```

This works fine, but I need to hard code each div to count and then populate.
Is there any better way to do it and not harcoded the number of elements like I did on currentDiv var?

Thanks

Comment: in your example, the values in the array are sequential with how they should be entered into the div - is that really the case?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `%` modulus operator to find out the even and odd as it give you remainder after division. If dividing number by 2 and remainder is zero then it even and if remainder is 1 then its odd.

```
for(var i=0; i<=myArray.length; i++){        
   if(currentDiv % 2 == 0){ 

   } 
   else{

   } 
}
```

You can currentDiv with i the loop increment variable, also I think loop counter is doing one extra iteration which I have adjust by starting `loop from i=1`.

```
for(var i=1; i<=myArray.length; i++){        
   if(i % 2 == 0){ 
        $('#s' + i + '').append("<p>"+myArray[i]+"</p>");
        console.log(myArray[i]);    
   } 
   else{
       console.log(myArray[i]);
       $('#s'+ i + '').append("<p>"+myArray[i]+"</p>");
       $('#container').append("</div>");
   } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but looks like is always appending to the first div. Will try something different.

Comment: I think problem was due to $('#s'+currendDivID+'') as currendDivID is not incremented in the solution. Change it to $('#s'+ i + '') will solve the problem. Please give it a try. I have updated my answer.

Comment: There is an extra `{` in `for(var i=0; i<=myArray.length; i++){ {`

Comment: @IanJennings, thanks for pointing out. I made the correction.

Answer (score 1):

use the modulus operator.

so `currentDiv % 2 == 0`  for even
`currentDiv % 2 == 1`  for odd

what it does is divide by 2 and compares the remainder (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division)

Comment: Got it. Thanks you o much. Just needed to add    currendDivID++; at the else statement

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr=['content','content2','content3','content4','content5'];

for(var i=0;i<=arrlen;i++){

        if(i%2==0){

            if(i!=(arrlen-1)){
                if(i!=arrlen){
                    console.log(arr[i]+" "+arr[i+1]);
                }else{
                    break;
                }
            }else{

                console.log(arr[i]);
            }

        }

    }
```